# Spark SQL query Group By value followed by list

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Have table(`Data`) like below:

```
color status  freq

red    y        1

blue   y        1

green   y       2
```

expected output :   `red,blue 1 green 2`

```
select color , freq from  data where status = 'y' group by(freq)
```

Now we want to get result as '`red,blue`' for `freq= 1` and `green` for `freq =2` 
 how to get list of colours group by freq,correct the above sql query.

when using `first(colour)` , it only returning first colour but expecting all the colours group by freq.

correct the SQL query as per output

Comment: Your data has `freq` column, but you select `frequency`.

Comment: sorry for typo error. select color,freq from data where status ='y' group by (freq).  please correct this query as per output

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question, include actual query you use, full traceback and [format the post appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)? Thanks.

Comment: Can there be another  row green y 3 as well implying overall green y 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
//import org.apache.spark.sql._
//import org.apache.spark.sql.types._ 

val df = Seq(
 ("green","y", 4),
 ("blue","n", 7),
 ("red","y", 7),
 ("yellow","y", 7),
 ("cyan","y", 7)
          ).toDF("colour", "status", "freq")

val df2 = df.where("status = 'y'") 
            .select($"freq", $"colour")
            .groupBy("freq")
            .agg(collect_list($"colour"))

df2.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+----+--------------------+
|freq|collect_list(colour)|
+----+--------------------+
|4   |[green]             |
|7   |[red, yellow, cyan] |
+----+--------------------+
```

Comment: how to pass this dataframe column(colour) value to spark sql query? Eg : val out = df3.filter($"colour" === colour column in df2) here df3 is another dataframe

Comment: Not sure I follow, you may need ask new question and probide example like you did here.

Comment: In the above example , df2 contains colour(list). now,we have to select status from DF (i.e) val status = df.filter($"colour"=== colour coloumn in df2).select($"status"). here how to pass colour column of df2 dynamically

Comment: the question was answered jn its original format you should note, there is a protocol here to follow